# How to calculate size of a label without adding it to a view?

Tags: ios, label, titanium, uilabel, appcelerator

In Titanium SDK before 2.0 the following snippet worked like a charm on iOS Apps:

```
var label = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: 'Sample Text',
    width: 'auto'
});
alert(label.width); // shows the pixel width of the label
```

With the new release of the 2.0+ SDK this seems to no longer be supported.

Is there a different approach available that does not involve events such as postlayout? Events will need a ansync. handling which adds too much work to the creation of views.

Comment: I don't know titanium, but do you have access to standard Cocoa routines? NSString's sizeWithFont is the standard iOS solution.

Comment: Not that I know of. As last solution I could access it by creating a small Objective-C Module that provides me access to some Cocoa routines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is dirty and more or less a workaround:

```
label.toImage().width
```

… represents the width by creating an image of the label first.